# SSRS expression count

Tags: reporting-services

I can use expression `=count(Fields!xxx.value, "DataSet1")` and return the total count.

But I have a field with Active and Not active and want to count for record with active. I use expression `=Count(IIf(Fields!xxx.Value = "Active", 1, Nothing))` and it will not work.

It said "the value expression for textbox uses an aggregate expression without scope. a scope is requiered for all aggregates use outside od a data region unless the export contains exactly one datadset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1:  you need to include the "DataSet1" scope in your field definition, like you did in the count which worked.

2:  instead of doing a count on your IIF statement, do a SUM of IIF([Condition Is True],1,0)

Comment: How do I add Dataset1 scope in xxx field. Please give more example. Thank you.

Comment: Try this:  =SUM(IIF((Fields!xxx.Value, "DataSet1") = "Active",1,0))

Comment: error "the value expression for textrun textbox.paragrahs[0] textrun[0] has scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. the scope parameter must be set to string constant is eaul to either the name of containing group the name of containing data region or the the name of dataset"

Comment: I miss ( in front Fields! then run again this time error he value expression for textbox uses an aggregate expression without scope. a scope is requiered for all aggregates use outside od a data region unless the export contains exactly one datadset"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a report set up like this to test on, so I am guessing at the exact syntax.   Try this:  =SUM(IIF(Fields!xxx.Value = "Active",1,0), "DataSet1")